# MySQL 5.7 select records by same uid but different keywords

Tags: mysql

Following table structur:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | UID        | KEYWORD                      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1 | UID_12345    | AERZTE                      |
| 2 | UID_12345    | RADIOLOGIE                  |
| 3 | UID_12345    | RADIOAKTIV                  |
| 4 | UID_12346    | ARZT                        |
| 5 | UID_12346    | RADIOLOGIE                  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

and now I will select the two rows where the keywords are: AERZTE and RADIOLOGIE and has the same UID. How can I do this?

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: The input is only AERZTE and RADIOLOGIE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need conditional aggregation for your desired rows

```
select *
from test
where keyword in ('AERZTE','RADIOLOGIE')
  and uid in (
    select uid
    from test
    group by uid
    having sum(case when keyword = 'AERZTE' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
      and  sum(case when keyword = 'RADIOLOGIE' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
  )
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df037f/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT uid 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE keyword IN ('AERZTE','RADIOLOGIE') 
 GROUP 
    BY uid 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

This assumes a unique key on (uid,keyword)